# Can someone please tell me whats the issue i am writing a starter code on remix from solidity: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '-'

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, smart-contract-wallets, parser

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract my_contract{
    string public mystring - "hello world!";

}
```

I have just started coding on solidity I have no previous experience so can someone explain what this parser error means :-
from solidity:
ParserError: Expected ';' but got '-'
--> my contract.sol:4:28:
|
4 |     string public mystring - "hello world!";
|                            ^

Comment: ` string public mystring - "hello world!";` here you want to assign a value of "hello world!" to a public string variable named `mystring`. Assignation is done with the `=` sign. change that line to `string public mystring = "hello world";` and you should be fine. The error is actually telling you that the `-` character is not expected, because it is invalid here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is assign the "hello world" value to the `mystring` variable, that should be done using a '=' and not a '-', if you change the code to this it should work:

```
string public mystring = "hello world!";
```